# Calculating near GPS coordinates in Django

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I have got a model in Django that stores a list of GPS coordinates for location. What I need to do is implement a search. I take the coordinates of the user from his device. What I need to do is show him locations nearby, and also the functionality that he can filter his search radius.

What we initially had in mind was to iterate through all the data and find matches. But that would be inefficient even with caching.

What I need to know is can I use Neo4j graph database for the same or should I stick to existing ORM.

In case of existing ORM, what is the most efficient way to write a search filter that returns me list of nearby locations.

In case of Neo4j, I am totally new and would appreciate if you can point me to some resources with a sample implementation for the same with Django.

Here is the current models that we are using

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals                                         
                                                                                
from django.db import models                                                    
from django.contrib.auth.models import User                                     
                                                                                
class Category(models.Model):                                                   
        name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = False)                
                                                                                
class Location(models.Model):                                                   
        name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True)                 
        cordinateX = models.FloatField(max_length = 50 , blank = False)         
        cordinateY = models.FloatField(max_length = 50 , blank = False)         
                                                                                
class Activity(models.Model):                                                   
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User,blank = True, null = True)               
        name = models.CharField(max_length = 100,blank = False)                 
        about = models.TextField(max_length = 500, blank = False)               
        location = models.ForeignKey(Location, blank = True, null = True)       
        category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank = True)               
        status = models.BooleanField(default = False)                           
        deleted = models.BooleanField(default = False)                          
        createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                     
                                                                                
        def __unicode__(self):                                                  
                return self.name
```

Can I use Neo4j graph database for this or should I stick to existing ORM?

Based on A comment, I am assuming using GeoDjango the Location should change, and lat,long should be replaced with `Point` from GeoDjango models.

This added another question, would there be problems in foreign key with existing models to geodjango models. The search filter should be able to fetch nearby `Activity` and show then in order nearest to farthest.

Comment: While neo4j might be able to do this for you geodjango is the right tool for the job

Comment: @e4c5 , i just looked a little bit into it, i am assuming to use PointField for all the coordinates, now how do i filter the same, there seems to be very less documentation about the same. Also i would appreciate i you can post an answer with simple, `filter near points`, ans insert using django form :)

Comment: gladly. Please post your model.

Comment: @e4c5 thanks for the help, i added the models, and also was not sure about this but geodjango has separate models, I can still reference them as foreign key from my existing models right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have [installed Geodjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/install/) you can convert your models to spatial
models by changing your import to

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
```

As you rightly guessed your Location model would change.

```
class Location(models.Model):                                                   
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True)                 
    coords = models.PointField()
```

Can you have a foreign key from `Activity` to `Location`? definitely yes. Your Activity model wouldn't need to change

As for fetching nearby activities and displaying them from the order of nearest to furthest. This is what your query is going to look like

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance
Activity.objects.annotate(
  distance=Distance('location__coords',somepoint)
).order_by('distance')
```

Where `somepoint` is a point object. You can even get fancy and allow `somepoint` to come from another model with the use of Django F objects.

At this stage I must warn you that whether you use geodjango or some other platform queries like the above might become slow if you have a very large number lot of locations in your database.

The secret to speeding up the query is to apply a filter that removes points that are too far way. That's where [dwithin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#dwithin) enters the picture.